# IF else in Calculate in Dax

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, daxstudio

I have a simple calculation `MyBase = SUM('MyData'[Amount])` and I would like to include an ifelse statement in `Calculate`. The condition is `IF [Currency Type] = "USD" THEN [MyBase]/2 Otherwise` print out the code below.

```
MyCalculate = 
CALCULATE(    
    [MyBase],
    KEEPFILTERS('MyData'[Currency] = "USD"),
    KEEPFILTERS('MyData'[Scenario] = "AOP")
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IF(
'MyData'[Currency] = "USD", 
[MyBase]/2, 
CALCULATE(    
    [MyBase],
    KEEPFILTERS('MyData'[Currency] = "USD"),
    KEEPFILTERS('MyData'[Scenario] = "AOP")
    )
)
```